# Test localized strings from swift package

Tags: swift, xcode

In my main part of the app we have the localizable.strings file and then we have modularized our app into packages and want to test if a computed property in the viewModel returns the correct string.

The ViewModel:

```
open class ScheduleHeaderViewModel {
    public var headingLabel: String {
        NSLocalizedString("schedule.header.title", comment: "Heading label")
    }
}
```

The Test:

```
class ScheduleHeaderViewModelTests: XCTestCase {
    private let store = AppStoreMock(
        initial: .mock(),
        reducer: AppState.reducer, middlewares: []
    )
    private let device = UIDeviceMock()
    private var viewModel: ScheduleHeaderViewModel!

    override func setUp() {
        viewModel = ScheduleHeaderViewModel(store: store, device: device)
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        store.reset()
        device.reset()
    }


    func testHeadingLabel() {
        XCTAssertEqual(viewModel.headingLabel, "schedule.header.title")
    }
}
```

The .strings file

```
"schedule.header.title" = "SCHEDULE";
```

Currently the test passes but it is returning "schedule.header.title" and should return "SCHEDULE"

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me if I use the full method:
`NSLocalizedString("key", bundle: Bundle.module, value: "value", comment: "comment")`. I think adding `Bundle.module` is what it needs here.